# Official Jasmine test 101 example for Angular2 and TypeScript does not work if class has @Pipe annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to setup jasmine tests as explained here in official angular 2 documentation - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html but the example for Pipe Testing just does not work. 
When I run the tests, I see only the specs for Hero working and the results coming to the browser.

If I comment out the Pipe annotation, only then the tests work :

````

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
//@Pipe({ name: 'my-uppercase' })
export class MyUppercasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

````

Can anyone help me what needs to be added to get the tests work with pipe annotations? The modified code after following the tutorial is available here - https://github.com/rohans84/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

The following setup works for me.

**Pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sample'
})
export class SamplePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return null;
  }

}
```

**Spec**

```
import { SamplePipe } from './sample.pipe';

describe('Pipe: Sample', () => {
  it('create an instance', () => {
    let pipe = new SamplePipe();
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**Testing Guide**

The testing guide is not up to date.
It's mentioned on the top of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

**[EDIT]**

I use Karma to run my tests. I have a setup for running Tests on GitHub: http://github.com/GregOnNet/angular2-testing-playground

I use [angular-cli](http://cli.angular.io) to manage my Angular 2 projects.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Greg, but this change absolutely had no impact on the issue. The tests still dont run if I have the Pipe annotation added. Updated my github repo with your change as well

Comment: Also, can you post the transpiled js code of both your spec and class file, as well as post the html file that loads the test file and additionally your systemjs config? I want to see what am I missing

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback,

The origin of the Problem might be that you use the HTML-Testrunner.
Like I said before the Testing-Guide is not up to date and may not work out of the Box.
I use Karma to run my tests.

You can have a look on my Repository on GitHub.
There I have a setup for running Tests: https://github.com/GregOnNet/angular2-testing-playground

Hope this helps